# jquery getscript for iframe object

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

I've got a dynamically created iframe that I'm trying to add a script to. For example:

var iframe = document.createElement("iframe");

I'd like to inject javascript into this iframe. I've got this working without using jquery by creating a script element under the iframe object and adding callbacks to this script object via the readystate & onReadyState events. Now I'd like to try the same thing with jquery.

However if I just do:

```
$.getScript(url,function() {
 myCallback();
});
```

My script(s) get added to the current document, and references from the iframe object are broken. How can I call getscript on an iframe object?

Tried this which didn't work:

```
var elementID = $(element).attr('id');
$('iframe#' + elementID).getScript(url, function(){
 myCallback();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The only way `.getScript` would work is if you executed it **on** the iframe as jquery automatically downloads and adds the script to the current `document`